# What file format would I use for currency exchange

Tags: currency, file-format

I'm looking for a standard file format that used by systems needing to store currencies and also provide currency exchange (so we need both the buy and sell rates)

I looked online and found the [.cex](http://filext.com/file-extension/CEX) but have not been able to find it's format.

Where do I get the format of this file?

Is there another file format I should use?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if [SERIFF](http://www.cloanto.com/specs/seriff.html) is any better for your application, but at least it has documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe [FIX](http://www.fixprotocol.org/) is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

FpML http://www.fpml.org/ might be what you're looking for.  If all you are doing is storing bid/ask then I don't think I'd saddle myself with XML.  What's wrong with storing it in a database?